# Is there a way to set a default function for getters and setters?

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

I was wondering if there is a way to set a default function for a getter or a setter.
For example, let's say I have this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsDirty {get; private set; } = false;

    private string _property;
    public string Property1 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _property1;
        } 
        set
        {
            if (value != _property1)
            {
                _property1 = value;
                IsDirty = true;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsDirty {get; private set;} = false;

    MyClass.defaultSet = { if (value != !_property1) { _property1 = value; IsDirty = true; } };

    private string _property1;
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 {get; set;}
    public string Property3 {get; set;}
   //...
}
```

So that I don't have to do it the first way on this big class I have (~100 properties).

Comment: why not extract a method from your setter and call it within every setter?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain: The name and type of `Property` will change for each property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding how PropertyChanged mechanism works (workflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043183/understanding-how-propertychanged-mechanism-works-workflow)

Comment: try this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316417/7364454, it's not possible to work with only a simple set;

Comment: Sounds like a problem where AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) may be helpful. Its not build in in C# but something like [postsharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) adds that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this doesn't exist, for several reasons:

1. Not every property is going to be a string, so this would need to correctly handle integers, DateTimes, Decimal, etc
2. Primitive value types are bad enough, but then start throwing in things like Tuples, complex classes (where changing a class member is still `get` operation on the property itself!), delegates, etc
3. If you reference a property by it's own name, you're creating a circular reference that will cause a StackOverflowException.
4. Not every property is going to use the same `Property` name, so that part of the method is different. You'd need another keyword or argument to the set method.
5. You need a way to exempt the `someBool` / `IsDirty` property.

Comment: Thanks man, fast and professional!
I will find some other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the noise by using a helper method like this

```
private void Set<T>(ref T field, T value)
{
  if (!Equals(value, field))
  {
    field = value;
    IsDirty = true;
  }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
public string Property1
{
  get => _property1;
  set => Set(ref _property1, value);
}
```